# How to order group results in linq

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a list of files say ***prg_3.txt , prg_2.txt , prg_1.txt .***

I need to loop over the files and merge the files in order 1,2,3 .

**The query i am using is as follows:**

```
var Groups = shortfilenames.GroupBy(s => s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf('_'))).ToList();
```

The above query would create a group names prg and it will have 3 files.

Now,i need to sort them in the order 1,2,3 i.e fromm their file names.

Here, I am getting grouped results, but i am not sure how to order the elements in each group

Please help..let me know incase of any questions..

**Edited :**

*Will it be good enough ?*

```
  var userGroups = shortfilenames.GroupBy(s => s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf('_'))).Select(g=>g.OrderBy(x=>x.Substring(x.IndexOf('_',x.Length-x.IndexOf('_')))));
```

Comment: Are your file names coming from SQL or is the `sql-order-by` tag a red herring?

Comment: No..its from C# application..its just linq order by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work but probably won't be so efficient:

```
shortfilenames
    .GroupBy(s => s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf('_')))
    .Select(
        g => g.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(new String(x.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray()))));
```

This will not work if your file contains additional digits, here is another solution to fix that, according to your comment this should work with the format you specified:

```
 shortfilenames
      .GroupBy(s => s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf('_')))
      .Select(g => g.OrderBy(
          x =>
             {
                 var index = x.IndexOf('_');
                 return int.Parse(x.Substring(index + 1, x.LastIndexOf('.') - index));
             }));
```

Comment: missing a couple of `)` ;)

Comment: Can you please explain the query. Here, the format of the file will be fixed, as xxxxx_digits

Comment: Can you please explain your query ?

Comment: It's getting the numbers in your query creates a new string from the numbers then parse that string to integer and performs the order based on that value

Answer (score 0):

Since the names kinda match, what's the problem with simply using the `OrderBy` and giving it the names ?

```
var v = new string[] {"prg_3.txt","prg_2.txt", "prg_1.txt"};

var sorted = v.OrderBy(name => name);
```

you get :

```
prg_1.txt 
prg_2.txt 
prg_3.txt
```

Comment: do you mean OrderBy ?

Comment: :) . I did ... i was at the process of changing it and adding the example

Comment: Here, i am grouping beacuse there can be multiple group of files like pr1,pr2,pr3 is one group and prg1,prg2 and prg3 can be other group.

Comment: I need the extension of above query that i have mentioned

Comment: Prg1,prg2,prg3 are txt files of one user  and pr1,pr2,pr3 are the txt files of another user. I need group files of each user and order them . I am unable to order by after doing group by

Comment: look at Selman22 answer. He's on it. Just add some `))` at the end

Answer (score -1):

If you want to sort inner groupings by file name this should do the trick:

```
shortfilenames.GroupBy(s => s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf('_'))).Select(g => g.OrderBy(e => e)).ToList();
```

Comment: as selman commented, will fail on 11 & 2 .Not sure why the downvote though